# Action by conjugation, orbits and isotropy groups

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let us consider the action of the orthogonal group $ O(n) $ by conjugation in the space of the square matrices $ \mathbb {R}^{n^{2}} $, that is $Ad: O (n) \times \mathbb {R}^ {n^ {2}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$, given by
$$ Ad (A, B) = ABA ^ {- 1}. $$

Note that this action is invariant due to the conjugation of $ O (n) $ on the space of the symmetric arrays $Sym (n) \subset \mathbb {R}^ {n^ {2}} $, a given that given $ B $ symmetric , we have to $$ (ABA ^ {- 1}) ^ T = ((A ^ {- 1}) ^ TB ^ TA ^ T) = (ABA ^ {- 1}) $$

Therefore, as $ G = O (n) $ orbits of the Ad action, this is the images of that action
$G (B) = \{Ad (A, B) = ABA ^{- 1} \}, $
are given by real symmetric matrices, as symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable, every orbit of this action goes through a diagonal matrix.

**My question**:

i) How to prove that this$Ad: O (n) \times Sym \longrightarrow Sym$ conjugation is an isometry?

ii) Find, in fact, the orbits of this action in $B \in Sym$ and find the isotropy groups $G_ {B}$